# Xlib parsed color not rendering

Tags: c, linux, colors, xlib, system-tray

I'm trying to make a system tray program for Linux (testing on alpine and debian on two different machines with different monitors and different video drivers).

```
// parse a color
XColor parsed;
parsed.flags = 0;

// input is white #FFFFFF
int found_color = XParseColor(dpy, wa.colormap, "#FFFFFF", &parsed);

// the above fails, but the following succeeds
// int found_color = XParseColor(dpy, wa.colormap, "#FF00FF", &parsed);
printf("found color: %x\n", found_color);

printf("parsed pixel: %d %d %d\n", parsed.red, parsed.green, parsed.blue);

if(XAllocColor(dpy,wa.colormap,&parsed) == 0){
    printf("Failed to allocate color\n");
    return 1;
}

printf("cm: %lx\n", wa.colormap);
printf("pp: %lu\n", parsed.pixel);

win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, parsed.pixel);
```

this outputs the following:

> found color: 1
>
> parsed pixel: 65280 65280 65280
>
> cm: 22
>
> pp: 16777215

Xlib finds the color defined by the code #FFFFFF, returns the corresponding u16 color levels, and then the decimal value 16777215, which is 0xFFFFFF.

So everything up through here looks good. But the window is simply transparent in my task bar. As mentioned in the commented-out XParseColor call, if I change the value to FF00FF, there's a nice little magenta square in my taskbar.

For some reason, certain values are just not rendering for me. Another example is #0000FF. 100% blue will not render, however #0100FF will!

I think I must just be missing something small in the color management layer, but I've been over the entire API, and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

I'm translating the color to an exact XColor, then I'm getting the approximated color supported by my hardware when I call XAllocColor.

(Full code available [here](https://gist.github.com/computermouth/3acf6df9b20a9ebfe1618a3846db5318))

Comment: All that I can tell you is: Works for me. Your "full code" gets me a white rectangle in the systray. The other colors that you mention all also work fine for me.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Oh, well that's at least some information. Could I ask what distro, xorg driver, an color map you've got?

Comment: Debian testing, modesetting driver, no idea what you mean with colormap but (as everything these days) my framebuffer uses 24 bpp.

Comment: Do the colors work when you create a "normal" window, i.e. when you just remove the call to `send_systray_message` from main?

Comment: @UliSchlachter they do! Interesting. 

That function was something I just copied off a forum post. Time to do some digging into those functions and types.

I also tried Debian (albeit stretch) with just the modesetting driver, and had the same results as before. As for the colormap, I mean the value printed at line 77, `wa.colormap`

Comment: That might then just be a bug in whatever provides your systray. Most systray windows use a transparent background.